# How to mock a Dao twice but being called with same Object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

How to mock a Dao which is being called in the test method twice with the same object but with the different internal state (of the parameter).

```
User user = new User();
user.setActivity(false);
int prevActivity = accessDao.calculateWork(user);
user.setActivity(true);
int predActivity = accessDao.calculateWork(user);


if(prevActivity==0) {
    //someAction
}

...

if(predActivity<15) {
    //someOtherAction.
}
```

I cannot change code. Is there any way in Mockito for the following situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mockito's answers for that.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
when(accessDao.calculateWork(user)).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
  Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() == 0) return someValue;
    return anotherValue;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you may be looking for?

```
accessDao = mock(AccessDao.class);
when(accessDao.calculateWork(user)).thenReturn(0).thenReturn(15)
```

You may instruct Mokcito to return firstly one answer, then another. Do note however that the last one will be "infinte repeated" ; i.e always return 15 (if you have even further calls to that method).